# Disable specific popupmenu value based on another popupmenu

Tags: matlab, user-interface, visibility, popupmenu

I have a GUI with 3 popupmenu controls.

The first one shows the following values:

```
a
b
c
```

The 2nd one:

```
b
b
c
```

The 3rd:

```
a
b
d
```

If the user chose on the 2nd popupmenu the value `c` for example, I had like to disable the 3rd option in all of the popupmenus because the 3rd popupmenu dont have the letter c in its 3rd option.

Is there a way to keep the values of the popupmenu visible but without the option to click on them?

Thank you.

Comment: According to Walter Roberson from [this post](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/301173-how-to-disable-specific-items-from-a-popup-menu-by-using-a-logical-vector-of-the-same-length-of-the#answer_232987): "It is not possible to disable individual items in a uicontrol('style', 'popup'). It is only possible to detect that one of them have been selected and to either return without doing anything or else automatically set the Value property to select something else."

Comment: A better solution is demonstrated [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/14542-disabling-specific-contents-of-a-popup-menu#answer_19764) where you can grey out the content then handle the callback. To grey out the content in the existing popupmenu, you will need `set(popup_1_handle, 'String', {'a', 'b', '<html><font color="gray">c</font></html>'});`

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I looked for.

Comment: @Anthony, Is there a way to do a condition that gray all the options that arent something? like instead of creating the list as you suggested just to make a loop that grays cells